# How to create OpenGL application for Android using PhoneGap (Cordova)?

Tags: android, cordova, opengl-es, ibm-mobilefirst

I want to develop an OpenGL application for Android with PhoneGap (or probably using "IBM Worklight"). Could anybody tell me where to start?

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to get started with Worklight there are a multitude of Presentations and Samples found here:

https://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.getstart.doc/start/c_gettingstarted.html

Here is the main page of the Infocenter which provides tons of information on all components of Worklight:

https://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.help.doc%2Fwl_home.html

Worklight even provides a free Developer Edition which you can download directly through the Eclipse Marketplace or find more information here:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/ws/worklight/